# How I can filter only quic packets with `tcpdump` command?

Tags: udp, tcpdump

I want to capture only QUIC UDP datagrams on 443 port.

With following command tcpdump reports all udp packets that arrive to the host on port 443.

```
tcpdump -n udp -SX -i any port 443
```

How I can set it up so tcpdump will print only QUIC packets?

Comment: What's wrong with your quoted filter?

Comment: It captures all datagrams, but I want to filter out all non QUIC packets.

Comment: What non-QUIC UDP datagrams do you think would be sent to port 443?